# How to iterate a sparse matrix of type int in Python

Tags: python

I am using mlnn from skmultilearn.adapt library for one of my classification problems. The ouput which predict functions give me is sparse matrix of type int.

```
mlk=mlknn.MLkNN(k=10)
mlk.fit(training_M,Y_train) 
output=mlk.predict(testing_M)
```

when i try to print the output like
    `print(output)`

it shows me only 1 output i.e.

```
(0, 1120)   1
```

But I need to read the full matrix and find the non zero values.

if I do

```
output[2][4]
```

it shows me `Row Index out of bound erro`

How can i avoid this error and get the row and column index of all the non zero values?

Answer (score 0):

This print is a condensed form and means that there is only one non-zero value in that matrix, otherwise there would be more output.

You can double-check this by calling `output.nnz`. (attribute, not function)

If you got enough memory, you can use `output.todense()` to obtain classic non-sparse numpy-arrays.

Otherwise look up the docs to see how to work with these more efficiently.

[scipy sparse docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/sparse.html)

**Remark**: your example `output[2][4]` shows that you are new to numpy/scipy and i highly recommend going through their docs. Indexing 2d-arrays / matrices is done like `output[2,4]`